# Mysql Select from table1 where row1 equals row1 in table2 in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Ok, so I can't seem to get this to work, but here is what I wan't to do. I have 2 tables one 
like this

```
Table1
----------
Row1
```

And this

```
Table2
----------
Row2
```

I want to get the data from Table1 where Row2 equals "thisvalue", in php. Any idea how I should go about doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You join the tables together

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.row1 = t2.row2
```

If you want only a row with a specific rw2-value, you can specify that in the WHERE clause

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.row1 = t2.row2 where t2.row='your value'
```